# Is there a way to rearrange terminals in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, window

I have multiple terminals open like this
[VS code Terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuNIH.jpg)

I want to drag and rearrange them as we can do for mac terminal tabs.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably covered by https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121500 (Add drag and drop support to Terminal Tabs).  And so not available yet.

Comment: I couldn't find reorder/rearrange term anywhere in the marster issue(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120241) I believe the closest is 4->1->6 Here but I dont understand what you mean by drag and drop for terminals but hopefully that what is drag and rearrange. It can aslo be the 4->1->3 if drag and rearrange is what is meant by "move to side". Basically if you have used terminal on macOS , thats exactly that I am looking for

Comment: I already have 7 of (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120241) . Hope you didn't mean that. did you? By the way are all these features live in latest version,  the planned date shows April 2021 in the github issue?

Comment: Ok so https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121500 is moved to May . Sp I'll wait. Let's see how it turns out to be,